# How to design a form with row and col span using antd grid?

Tags: reactjs, antd

Here i am adding my sample code. i am getting a form but i didn't get space between  the text fields.How to get it?

```
import React from "react"
import { Form, Row, Col, Input, Button, Icon } from 'antd'



class MidTermForm extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Row gutter={8}>
                    <Col xs={2} sm={16} md={12} lg={8} xl={10}><b>Topic</b></Col>
                    <Col xs={20} sm={4} md={6} lg={8} xl={4}><b>MaximuScore*</b></Col>
                    <Col xs={2} sm={4} md={6} lg={8} xl={10}><b>Student's Score</b></Col>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    <Col xs={2} sm={16} md={12} lg={8} xl={10}>Written Exam</Col>
                    <Col xs={20} sm={4} md={6} lg={8} xl={4}><Input /> </Col>
                    <Col xs={20} sm={4} md={6} lg={8} xl={4}><Input /> </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    <Col xs={2} sm={16} md={12} lg={8} xl={10}>Oral Exam and Class Participation</Col>
                    <Col xs={20} sm={4} md={6} lg={8} xl={4}><Input /> </Col>
                    <Col xs={20} sm={4} md={6} lg={8} xl={4}><Input /> </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    <Col xs={2} sm={16} md={12} lg={8} xl={10}>Homework and Projects</Col>
                    <Col xs={20} sm={4} md={6} lg={8} xl={4}><Input /> </Col>
                    <Col xs={20} sm={4} md={6} lg={8} xl={4}><Input /> </Col>
                </Row>
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

Now i want to display a form same as given midterm form.How to get background color and how to get space between the two text fields?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

@laxmi- 
Antd provides some classes which really useful styling and posting the form. use `Form.Item` it has some custom margin and padding  you can use `<col span={8}/>` also you can use `getfielddecorator`

```
     const FormItem = Form.Item;
     <div>
<Form>

                    <Row gutter={8}>
                        <Col xs={2} sm={16} md={12} lg={8} xl={10}><b>Topic</b></Col>
                        <Col xs={20} sm={4} md={6} lg={8} xl={4}><b>MaximuScore*</b></Col>
                        <Col xs={2} sm={4} md={6} lg={8} xl={10}><b>Student's Score</b></Col>
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                        <Col xs={2} sm={16} md={12} lg={8} xl={10}>Written Exam</Col>
                        <Col xs={20} sm={4} md={6} lg={8} xl={4}><Form.Item><Input /><Form.Item/> </Col>
                        <Col xs={20} sm={4} md={6} lg={8} xl={4}><Form.Item><Input /><Form.Item/></Col>
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                        <Col xs={2} sm={16} md={12} lg={8} xl={10}>Oral Exam and Class Participation</Col>
                        <Col xs={20} sm={4} md={6} lg={8} xl={4}><Form.Item><Input /><Form.Item/> </Col>
                        <Col xs={20} sm={4} md={6} lg={8} xl={4}><Form.Item><Input /><Form.Item/></Col>
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                        <Col xs={2} sm={16} md={12} lg={8} xl={10}>Homework and Projects</Col>
                        <Col xs={20} sm={4} md={6} lg={8} xl={4}><Form.Item><Input /><Form.Item/> </Col>
                        <Col xs={20} sm={4} md={6} lg={8} xl={4}><Form.Item><Input /><Form.Item/> </Col>
                    </Row>
</Form>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Table from antd and add custom components to it's columns like Form.

[Codepen Working Example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NoJopL)

```js
const { Table, Divider, Tag, Input } = antd;

const columns = [{
  title: 'Topic',
  dataIndex: 'topic',
  key: 'topic',
  render: text => <div style={{ backgroundColor: "lightblue", padding: 10 }}>{text}</div>,
}, {
  title: 'Maximum Score',
  dataIndex: 'maxScore',
  key: 'maxScore',
  render: maxScore => <Input value={maxScore} />
}, {
  title: 'Students score',
  dataIndex: 'studentScore',
  key: 'studentScore',
  render: studentScore => <Input value={studentScore} />
}, ];

const data = [{
  key: '1',
  topic: 'Written Exam',
}, {
  key: '2',
  topic: 'Oral Exam',
}, {
  key: '3',
  topic: 'Homework Project',
}];

ReactDOM.render(<Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} pagination={false} />, mountNode);
```

```css
@import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/antd/3.13.5/antd.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="padding: 24px"></div>
<script>
  var mountNode = document.getElementById('container');
</script>
```

Comment: i have Attendence column  have three rows of data but its displaying all data its a single column and Teacher comments is textarea but its gets textields how do it slove a problem?

Comment: Change the column component to textare component

Comment: link was not opened.How to change it already i have 3 columns in this 2 columns we have declare as textfield if i change the the columns was textarea its changed also previous columns

Comment: How it works?how to display the Attendence text with 3 rows and how to add textarea only for one row?

Comment: Or just hire me for the task

Comment: ok i have to try with out table using grid with pull and push the data with alignment

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use style inside

```
  <Col style={{backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0)', border: 0 }} xs={2} sm={16} md={12} lg={8} xl={10}><b>Topic</b></Col>
```

to give background color.

You can also style with other properties.